# Repeat each value n times as rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to achieve this in SQL (Oracle 11g) for a while but could not find a proper way to do it.

My table `names` has the following rows:

```
NAME      REPEAT
----      ------
KAUSHIK   2
KARTHIK   3
NIDHI     1
ASHWINI   5
JAGADEESH 6
```

What I need is an output like this:

```
NAME
----
KAUSHIK    -- 2 rows
KAUSHIK
KARTHIK
KARTHIK    -- 3 rows
KARTHIK
NIDHI      -- 1 row
ASHWINI
ASHWINI    -- 5 rows
...
```

and so on.

One of the queries  which I have tried so far, which of course is not working. I tried to use `unpivot` as well but could not seem to find a proper way to accomplish this.

```
SELECT m.name
FROM names m
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT name, repeat FROM names
  ) n
ON m.name = n.name
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= n.repeat;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from names
cross join (select rownum n from dual
            connect by level <= (select max(repeat) from names))
where n <= repeat
order by name
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use some temp table containing list of numbers 1 to N, where N is the highest number in your table `names`. Let call it `num(o int)` Then the query will be

```
SELECT *
FROM names, num
WHERE num.o <= names.repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

If we presume that your all_objects system object has more objects than the max repeat...

```
SELECT n.name
FROM names n
LEFT JOIN (Select rownum from all_objects) z
 on z.rowNum < n.repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found an alternative with connect by and correlated sub-query.

```
select name
from   names o
connect by level <= ( select repeat from names 
                        i where i.name = o.name )
AND                        
prior name = name and
           prior sys_guid() is not null
           order by name;
```